# "[Errno 256] No more mirrors to try."

Tags: fedora, system-installation, installer-anaconda

I am having some problem installing 32-bit Fedora20 OS over the network. At the installation summary page, under the software installation source section, using the default closest mirror option, I keep getting the following fatal error during installation:

```
The following error occurred while installing.
This is a fatal error and installation will be aborted.

error populating transaction: failure:
Packages/b/biosdevname-0.5.0-2.fc20.i686.rpm from anaconda:
[Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

As it appears that Fedora has some problem locating mirrors, I tried manually specifying a URL for the base repository, such as:

```
http://ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/linux/fedora/releases/20/Fedora/i386/os/
```

I tried a few URLs, but all, except the URL closest to where I stay which causes the above fatal error, give me the following error:

> Error setting up base repository

Am I missing something?

Comment: The mirror is correct. Did you tried with other mirrors?

Comment: @Braiam, as mentioned above, I did tried manually entering a few other mirror URLs. All didn't work. I suspect the culprit is DNS as after I have given up and install using a full DVD version, I face similar problem doing `yum update`. I have to manually delete the router ip from the list of nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` to be able to do an update. If I can do the same prior to installing the OS, then maybe I can get the network installation to work.